# AuthZforce use without fiware enablers

Tags: fiware, fiware-wilma, authzforce

Can the Fiware enabler AuthZforce be used without keyrock and wilma? 
can it be used using others pep and IDM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. The [AuthZForce API](http://authzforce-ce-fiware.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UserAndProgrammersGuide.html) is not designed specifically for KeyRock/Wilma. Just to clarify, KeyRock consumes the PAP API of AuthZForce, and Wilma consumes the PDP API of AuthZForce. To achieve that, the KeyRock/Wilma team have developed their own AuthZForce API *connectors*, i.e. the client part that consumes AuthZForce API. So if you use another PEP/IdM, you have to develop a similar *connector* for this particular PEP/IdM, if it is not already there. A the [end of the user guide](http://authzforce-ce-fiware.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UserAndProgrammersGuide.html#software-libraries-for-clients-of-authzforce-or-other-authorization-pdp-geis), we give some hint to help develop your own Authzforce API client. In any case, all you need is a good HTTP/REST/XML framework to start with.

Regards,
Cyril